# При зуммировании линии графика выходят за рамки

Tags: javascript, диаграммы, extjs

```
var zoomArea = {
                            x: selection.x - me.el.getX(),
                            width: selection.width
                        };

                        var xScale = me.chartBBox.width,

                            zoomer = {
                                x: zoomArea.x / xScale,
                                width: zoomArea.width / xScale
                            };

                        var ends = me.axes.items[1].calcEnds();
                        var from = (ends.to - ends.from) * zoomer.x + ends.from;
                        var to = (ends.to - ends.from) * zoomer.width + from;

                        me.axes.items[1].fromDate = from;
                        me.axes.items[1].toDate = to;

                        me.setZoom(selection);
                        me.mask.hide();

                        me.refresh();
```

После зуммирования  линии графика выходят за пределы графика. Как с этим бороться?

[image]